# discord.js TypeError: server.roles.find is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, discord.js

I've made my own Discord Bot recently, and my command wouldn't work. So I checked my logs and the following error showed up.

Error with Event "Find Role", Action #1:
TypeError: server.roles.find is not a function

Any possible fixes for this?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: My command.json code?

Comment: Sure, just show the part of your code that you are getting the error in

Comment: https://pastebin.com/krAuJYqb

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Answer (score 1):

Roles is now a [manager](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/class/BaseManager) with the following methods: [create](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=create), [fetch](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=fetch), [resolve](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=resolve), [resolveID](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=resolveID).

Instead, use [roles' fetch method](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=fetch), returning a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```js
await server.roles.fetch(id)
```

Other changes and depreciations in v12 are outlined [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html).

Comment: Where should I insert this? Sorry, I'm just new at this.

Comment: Your error log reads: `server.roles.find` which will also tell you the file and line number where it was invoked. Please include the affected source in your question and we can answer accordingly.

Comment: It looks like this command is tripping whatever is accessing Discord roles; we'd need to see whichever utility or function is accessing your guild's roles when executing this command.

Answer (score 0):

They changed the discord API lately, it's not servers.roles.find but

```
server.roles.cache.find()
```

Comment: Doesn't find() take a function? Not too sure though

Comment: Yes. See [find under collections' cache](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=find). This is similar to the [filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: I wrote out of memory, didn't actually check eheh